# How do I get the Azure SQL instance name? How to set the minimal tls version to none on Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I can't connect to my azure SQL bc of the minimal tls set in my Azure SQL database. I saw this

```
az sql mi update -n instancename -g resourcegroup --set minimalTlsVersion="None"
```

statement to empty my minimal vls. I'm not sure if it works but I don't know the instance name for my Azure SQL database.

Can anyone share your solution here? Really appreciate for your help

Answer (score 0):

***Are you using the Azure SQL Database or Managed Instance? Both are different.***

For Azure SQL Managed Instance, The command to update tls setting should be as below:

```
az sql mi update -g <YourResourceGrp> -n <YourAzureSQLInstanceName> --minimal-tls-version="None"
```

Here the instance name is the name of your Azure SQL Managed Instance which is blacked out in below screenshot:

[image]

For Azure SQL Database, we cannot disable tls and it has to be set to either of 1.0,1.1,1.2 by using below command:

```
az sql server update -g <YourResourceGrp> -n <YourSqlServerName> --minimal-tls-version="1.0"
```